# How to update image using parse Android?

Tags: android, bitmap, parse-platform, sparse-file

I want to fetch image from table 1 to update image in table 2 on parse here is my code

```
 ParseFile image= ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getParseFile("image");

    if(image==null)
    {

    }
    else
    {
        try {
            byte[] data=image.getData();


            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory
                  .decodeByteArray(
                          data, 0,
                          data.length);


          // Set the Bitmap into the
          // ImageView
          image1.setImageBitmap(bmp);




        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

This code is working perfect it retrieves and set image properly now I want this "image" to upload in my Second table I am doing this

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("XYZ");
          String user_id=ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId();
        query.getInBackground(user_id, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {

            @Override
            public void done(ParseObject pdata, ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                pdata.put("image",image); // this line throw NullPointerException
                pdata.saveInBackground();
            }
        });
```

What I am doing wrong anyone please help?

Comment: Image is stored as a FILE

Comment: i did it but still throw exception

Comment: what is the exception? post your logcat

Answer (score 0):

You need ParseFile object. Try the following code. (It works fine, I just checked it)

```
               byte[] pfArray = getBytesFromBitmap(bmp);
                ParseFile file = new ParseFile("abc.png", pfArray);
                // Upload the image into Parse Cloud
                file.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        System.out.println("saved");

                    }
                });

public byte[] getBytesFromBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 70, stream);
        return stream.toByteArray();
    }
```

hope it helps.

Comment: Bitmap image=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path); i am asking about this path

Comment: If you're getting the bitmap then just pass it. Understand the code before down voting.

Comment: byte[] pfArray = getBytesFromBitmap(bmp); <- use this!

Comment: getBytesFromBitmap is not builtin method

Comment: String user_id=ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId();
   ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Create_Meetup");
   query.whereEqualTo("Userid", user_id);
   query.getInBackground(user_id, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
    
    @Override
    public void done(ParseObject pdata, ParseException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      byte[] pfArray = getBytesFromBitmap(bmp);
      ParseFile file = new ParseFile("img.txt", pfArray);
     pdata.put("image",file);
     pdata.saveInBackground();
    }
   });

doing this and got the same exception

Comment: Use some sort of validation for your own good.. In done:


 public void done(ParseObject pdata, ParseException e) {
if(pdata==null){}else{ that code }

Comment: in my logcat it show value "com.parse.ParseFile@42ebb0b0"

but at this line  pdata.put("image",file);

its throws NullPointerException :(

Comment: `com.parse.ParseFile@42ebb0b0` is the object not the file.